# Why PHP can't use Sqlsrv_connect with cmd

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd, sqlsrv

I make sure that I can run website with WampServer,and also can connect the Sql Server.However,I run the bat file by the operating system scheduler,that return error:

```
OK,Can Run PHP
Fatal error: Uncaught Error:Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\shell.php
Stack trace:
#0{main}
 thrown in C:\wamp64\www\shell.php
```

My configuration : WampServer 3.0.6 64bits (PHP 7.0.10, Apache 2.4.23)

There are my steps:

First: I wrote a bat file in \wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe -q C:\test.php
PAUSE
```

Second: The function sql_connect is basic on php

```
echo "OK,Can Run PHP";
$serverName = "------";  
$uid = "------";
$pwd = "------"; 
$connectionInfo = array("UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>"------","characterset"=>"utf-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn == false){
echo "Error<br>";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

}
else{
echo "OK<br>";  
}
```

Third: Put the bat in the operating system scheduler(Win7 64bit)

The cmd also can work by php -v and php -f.I think that cmd can work PHP with bat on the operating system scheduler because it answer "OK,Can Run PHP".
And then,the problem maybe is in "sqlsrv_connect()".
However,I really don't know that why the function "sqlsrv_connect()" can work in localhost website but can't work cmd without website. Please help me!!

Comment: Are you actually running SQL Server or just MySQL?

Comment: Yes,I just call php to connect SQL Server

Comment: Not sure if this is still the case, but WAMP used to ship with 2 php.ini files -
 one for the Apache server and one for the PHP CLI. Have you checked to see if the sqlsrv extensions are added in the php.ini for the CLI?

Comment: Hi ImClarky, Did you say that I need to set two extensions in the php.ini? 1.extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
2.extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll 
or other cmd for CLI?

Comment: And I try to run some instructs:
1.C:\Users\user>php -v

Answer=>

PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2016 09:48:53) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

2.C:\Users\user>php -i 

[PHP Modules] => It doesn't have sqlsrv.

Did you think problems are in the PHP modules?

Comment: @iChia - WAMP normally has 2 php.ini files. One of them is for the Apache Server which is located somewhere like `C:\wamp\bin\apache\ApacheX.X.X\bin\php.ini` - This is the one I think you have edited. The other php.ini file is for the PHP CLI which is found at something like `C:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.X\php.ini`. This is the file you need to add the two sqlsrv extensions to, to make your batch file work as it is using the PHP CLI and not the Apache server.

Comment: @ImClarky I have been check the extension in this file like
C:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.X\php.ini. 
1.extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
2.extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll 
There are in there but the PHP CLI still doesn't work.